# XML not parsing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

When I try to parse my [PHP-generated XML file](http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/scrape.php?id=1) using the [jQuery Feeds](https://github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds) plugin, it doesn't do what it's supposed to - loop through the template below and output the XML `<title>` tag in the place of `<!=title!>`. Instead, it returns just one instance of the template with nothing in place of `<!=title!>`.

Nothing is returned in the Chrome JavaScript console.

Strangely, I have a [similar PHP-generated XML file](http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/scrape2.php?id=1) that works just fine.

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
$('.feed').feeds({
    feeds: {
        feed1: 'http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/scrape.php?id=1' // this one doesn't work
    },
    //max: 3,
    loadingTemplate: '<h1 class="feeds-loader">Loading items...</h1>',
    entryTemplate:  '<div class="item"><a href="http://google.com"><div class="image"><img src="images/tie.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div></a>' +
                    '<div class="text"><ul class="list-inline">' +
                    '<li><span class="price text-warning"><strong>&pound;7.00</strong></span> <span class="text-muted"><strike>&pound;14.00</strike></span></li>' +
                    '<li class="text-muted"><strong>Topman</strong></li></ul>' +
                    '<!=title!>' +
                    '</div></div>'
});
```

Here's the code that generates the XML file:

```
<?php

function scrape($list_url, $shop_name, $photo_location, $photo_url_root, $product_location, $product_url_root, $was_price_location, $now_price_location, $gender, $country) {

    header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8");

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss/>');
    $xml->addAttribute("version", "2.0");
    $channel = $xml->addChild("channel");


    $channel->addChild("product_url", $product_url);
    $channel->addChild("shop_name", $shop_name);
    $channel->addChild("photo_url", $photo_url);
    $channel->addChild("was_price", $was_price);
    $channel->addChild("now_price", $now_price);


    $html = file_get_contents($list_url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

    if(!empty($html)) {

        $doc->loadHTML($html);
        libxml_clear_errors(); // remove errors for yucky html
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

        /* FIND LINK TO PRODUCT PAGE */

        $products = array();

        $row = $xpath->query($product_location);

        /* Create an array containing products */
        if ($row->length > 0)
        {            
            foreach ($row as $location)
            {
                $product_urls[] = $product_url_root . $location->getAttribute('href');
            }
        }
        $imgs = $xpath->query($photo_location);

        /* Create an array containing the image links */
        if ($imgs->length > 0)
        {            
            foreach ($imgs as $img)
            {
                $photo_url[] = $photo_url_root . $img->getAttribute('src');
            }
        }

        $result = array();

        /* Create an associative array containing all the above values */
        foreach ($product_urls as $i => $product_url)
        {
            $result = array(
                'product_url' => $product_url,
                'shop_name' => $shop_name,
                'photo_url' => $photo_url[$i]
            );

            $item = $channel->addChild("item");
            $item->addChild("product_url", $result['product_url']);
            $item->addChild("shop_name", $result['shop_name']);
            $item->addChild("photo_url", $result['photo_url']);
        }

        //print_r($result);

    }
    else
    {
        echo "this is empty";
    }
    echo $xml->asXML();
}

/* CONNECT TO DATABASE */

$dbhost = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$dbuser = "xxx";
$dbpass = "xxx";

$con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

/* GET FIELDS FROM DATABASE */

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM scrape WHERE id = '$id'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $list_url = $row['list_url'];
    $shop_name = $row['shop_name'];
    $photo_location = $row['photo_location'];
    $photo_url_root = $row['photo_url_root'];
    $product_location = $row['product_location'];
    $product_url_root = $row['product_url_root'];
    $was_price_location - $row['was_price_location'];
    $now_price_location - $row['now_price_location'];
    $gender = $row['gender'];
    $country = $row['country'];

    scrape($list_url, $shop_name, $photo_location, $photo_url_root, $product_location, $product_url_root, $was_price_location, $now_price_location, $gender, $country);
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: So basically you're saying you've downloaded a free plugin and it's not working like you would like it to work ?

Comment: I'm saying I'm trying to find the difference between two similar files, one of which works with the plugin and one of which doesn't.

Comment: So the question is really more about the XML files than the plugin.